# How to apply full background image in asp.net MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to asp.net MVC and I need to have a full background image on the login page. Im getting confused with all of the cshtmls and getting lost on where to set the full background image. Help please..

Comment: Your question it's about HTML/CSS not ASP.NET MVC, By the way, you can define a layout for your login page.

Comment: This is a more CSS Specific question really. You need the image and in the Shared Views folder there is a partial view for the login page, if you want a full background you cannot use a partial view, you will need to use a regular view without a layout.

Answer (score 7):

I think that best solutions is to do that via style sheets (css). All styles should be in a separate css file. For beautiful code don't use in-line styling:

```
body {
    background-image: url('your_img_path');
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: You have missed some of the facts. He needs to use it on a MVC login page, so he needs to change the login page referencing the layout really.

Comment: @Jamie Rees -  yes, you are right. He must do everything you said in your comment under his question and than use my small hint

Answer (score 3):

Firstly I would say, treat '.cshtml' just like '.html' for all designing purposes.
To add background image in a view (.cshtml page in Asp.net MVC), you simply need  to add it in  **< body >**  tag as **'background'** attribute.
I have provided the sample code. Have a Look.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Login Page</title>

</head>

<body background="~/Content/Images/sahb.png">
</body>

</html>
```

Regards!
SAHB

Answer (score 2):

In case if you want change background in a particular **View** just add thise code

```
@section head{
    <style type="text/css">
         body {
            background-image: url('/Images/paper.jpg');
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
}
```

But dont forget in **Layout** of this **View** add following line

```
<head>

  @RenderSection("head", required: false)

</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you wanna use background-image: url('');
just do not use ~ symbol

Answer (score 1):

If you want it on all pages use Shared/_Layout.cshtml file
and change body tag similar to

Probably I would put only on the Home/Index.cshtml page so it appears only on the home page
To avoid that repeated across other pages I would add an ID to home page in the Shared/Index.chtml file as follows
`<body id="HomepageBody" >`
and change it in the Content/site.css file add 
 `#HomepageBody {     background-image: url("/images/7flowers.jpg" ); 
                    background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;   }`

That would make it work across popular browsers like Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

use this code in cshtml page to insert background image on entire screen of your div section

```html
<div style="background-image: url('/Areas/Admin/Content/Image/OIP7.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100% 100%">
```

one more thing ~ is not working in Url. start your image address with forward slash
/ link this '/Areas/Admin/Content/Image/OIP7.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

In Index.cshtml:

```
    @{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/CSS/Main.css" />
</head>
<body 

</body>

</html>
```

in Main.css:

```
body {
background-image: url(../Images/myBackgroundPictureName.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple just use a css property background image on that div or that section you want.

```
<div style="background-image: url('/Content/images/image_2.jpg');"></div>
```

If your image is not displaying, you may have to add ~ tilde sign to the URL

Example :

```
 <div style="background-image: url('~/Content/images/image_2.jpg');"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the css property background-image and don't use the '~' symbol.

Ex: `<div background-image: url('/Images/abc.png')></div>`