# ASP MVC: Upload Image from Database as Full Background CSS

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm still fiddling with MVC and I want to set a **full background image which would be retrieved from the database**.

This is what I used to do in CSS and love to do whenever I need full background:

```
.banana3-sm{
    background-image: url('../images/banana3-sm.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Below is what I'm using currently because I don't know how to upload the image link from database to CSS.

**In Controller:**

```
model.ImgSrc = Convert.ToBase64String(model.Image);
```

**In CSHTML:**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 visible-md visible-lg">
    @Html.Partial("_ProductImage", Model)
</div>
```

**In PartialView**

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="@imgSrc" alt="Product Image" />
```

But the image isn't as responsive as I want it to be in the above `<img>` way.

So there a way I could insert the image link into here dynamically?

```
background-image: url('xx/xx/xxxx.png');
```

Thanks in advance!

And I have already read these similar threads as well on here:

[how-to-apply-full-background-image-in-asp-net-mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222608/how-to-apply-full-background-image-in-asp-net-mvc)

[css-background-image-refuses-to-display-in-asp-net-mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821921/css-background-image-refuses-to-display-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: If the CSS style is in a separate file, you may try using JS for img tag to manipulate default background: `$(".img-responsive").css("background-image", "url('@Url.Content("~/path/image/from/DB")')" );`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thanks mate. Will try it out now.

Comment: why don't use the style on div? Something like this: style="background-image: url(@Model.imgSrc)"

Comment: So I tried something like you suggested. <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 visible-md visible-lg product-img" style="background-image: url('@Url.Content(@imgSrc)');"> And I'm getting a background-image: url('data:image/png;xxxAVERYLONGSTRINGxxx'); But no image.

Comment: <div class="product-img" style="background-image: url(@imgSrc);"> didn't work as well. Any idea? =(

Comment: try this instead: <div style="background:url(data:image/png;base64,@imgSrc)" ></div>

Comment: I now get an error that says ERR_INVALID_URL. It must be sth like that for sure, what am I missing?

Comment: It finally worked guys! Thanks a load for your help (: