# Asp Mvc : set inline css background-image:url with an image stored in the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I store images in the database and can retrieve them in a view thanks to a Get Method from my Img Controller that returns a `File([] fileContents, string contentType)`.

No problem to display it in a View with :

`<img src="@Url.Action("Get", "Img", new { id = Model.ImgId})"`

On the contrary, when I try to pass the URL of an image within an inline background-image: url, it does not work.

1) I tried this in the View using the same Img Controller to get the image :

```
<div style="background-image: url('@Url.Action("Get", "Img", new { id = Model.ImgId})')"></div>
```

Which renders this HTML but does not display the image :

```
<div class="imageBox" style="background-image: url('/Img/Get/2')"></div>
```

2) I tried this in the User Controller :

`string formatWithoutPoint = user.Img.Format.Substring(1);
string imageBase64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(user.Img.Data);
string imageDataURL = string.Format("data:image/" + formatWithoutPoint + ";base64,{0}", imageBase64Data);
ViewBag.ImgSrc = imageDataURL;`

And this in the View :

`<div class="img" style="background-image: url('@ViewBag.ImgSrc')"></div>`

which renders this HTML but does not display the image :

```
<div style="background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAU...')"></div>
```

I don't understand... have you any idea?

I know someone had the same problem but he did not share how he finally managed to solve it : [ASP MVC: Upload Image from Database as Full Background CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47009912/asp-mvc-upload-image-from-database-as-full-background-css)

Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks Mate, that was my fault...

Answer (score 0):

I am such an idiot !

I was so focused on the background-image: url ('...') because the color syntax of visual studio would not get right that I completely forgot to give a size to that damn div !

Both methods are actually working well and displaying the image.

Sorry about that