# Adding a background image in ASP.NET to cover entire screen

Tags: html, css, asp.net, razor, razor-pages

I am using Razor Pages in ASP.NET and trying to add a background image while maintaining my text and picture over the background image. I am adding in the `<html>` tag instead of the `<body>` tag. My previous implementations were not covering the page, just part of it.

I think best practice is to add the background image to the html tag as I said above but I am not sure what to write into the html code.

Here is my CSS and HTML(index) code below:

```
<style type ="text/css" >

html {
    background-image: url('~/data/backgroundimage.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 100%;
}


.fade-in {
    animation: fadeIn ease 5s;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease 5s;
    -moz-animation: fadeIn ease 5s;
    -o-animation: fadeIn ease 5s;
}
```

```
@page
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Mock Website!";
}
<html>

<head>
    <link href="~/css/website.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="text-center">
        <img src="~/data/icon.png" />
        <h1 class="display-4">Hello!</h1>
        <div class="fade-in">
            <h2 class="display-4">How can I help you?</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `<body>` with [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size):

`cover`:

> Scales the image as large as possible without stretching the
> image. If the proportions of the image differ from the element, it is
> cropped either vertically or horizontally so that no empty space
> remains.

```
body { 
    background-image: url(~/data/backgroundimage.jpg); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-size:cover; 
}
```

See also: [How to apply full background image in asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222608/how-to-apply-full-background-image-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I tried your suggested solution but it didn't add anything to the background of the website. I also added the HTML portion in the first answer of the link with both your solution and separately.

Comment: Could you verify that css is loaded on your page and body element has css?

Comment: body element does not have css but header does. Should my css reference be in <html> instead of <header>? I also got the html answer in your link to work by changing the beginning of the path from ~ to ..

Comment: I mean when you open the page, can you see your css is loaded? I suspect your css path is not correct. And you should add also `type="text/css"` remove `media` property  as  `<link href="../css/website.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>` (It should be okay to put css reference to the header btw)

Comment: ok so, I did as you suggested. And yes my css is loaded, and my .fade-in is working.

Comment: When you inspect your body, do you see CSS attributes like `background-image`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223891/discussion-between-selim-yildiz-and-hotwheels).

Comment: So I fixed it, I just deleted website.css and used site.css as that was loaded by default in the package structure by .NET. Your code worked perfectly then.